# Python2 float object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is what i am trying to do:

```
if len(targets) == 0:
   avg = frozenset([tuple(.123/(nodes_num - 1))])
   for t in range(nodes_num):
       if t == node:
          continue
       node_p = (avg,t)
       node_weig.append(node_p)
```

I don't know what i am doing wrong but all it says `avg = fro...` float object is not iterable

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem: `tuple(.123/(nodes_num - 1))`

The `tuple` constructor takes an iterable and makes a `tuple` from the values it produces. Obviously, `.123/(nodes_num - 1)` is a `float`, which can't be iterated. If you want to make a one element `tuple` of this value, use: `(.123/(nodes_num - 1),)` (note: That trailing comma is necessary to make a one element `tuple`, otherwise the parens are just grouping the operation, not wrapping it in a `tuple`).

So the resulting line would be:

```
avg = frozenset([(.123/(nodes_num - 1),)])
```

That will make a `len` 1 `frozenset` containing a `len` 1 `tuple` with the calculated `float` value. If the goal is just a `frozenset` of that one value, you don't need the `tuple` wrapping at all, and can simplify to:

```
avg = frozenset([.123/(nodes_num - 1)])
```

Now, whether either does anything meaningful for your scenario I don't know, but it's the source of your error.

Answer (score 0):

From the doc:

[tuple([iterable])](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple)

> Return a tuple whose items are the same and in the same order as
>   iterable‘s items. **iterable** may be a sequence, a container that
>   **supports iteration**, or an **iterator object**. If iterable is already a
>   tuple, it is returned unchanged.

`.123/(nodes_num - 1)` is a float,that's why you got the error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

If I don't misunderstand your meaning,you can try to use

`tuple([.123 / (nodes_num - 1)])` to make it iterable.